# Why do I have an infinite loop in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, infinite-loop

Below I have a piece of code which calculates credit card balance, but it doesn't work when `balance` has an extreme value (such as `balance=9999999999`below). It throws the code through an infinite loop. I have a couple of theories as to how to fix this flaw, but don't know how to move forward with them. Here's my code:

```
balance = 9999999999
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyPayment = 0

monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate /12
newbalance = balance
month = 0

while newbalance > 0:
    monthlyPayment += .1
    newbalance = balance

    for month in range(1,13):
        newbalance -= monthlyPayment
        newbalance += monthlyInterestRate * newbalance
        month += 1
print("Lowest Payment:" + str(round(monthlyPayment,2)))
```

My theory is that
`while newbalance > 0`
is causing the infinite loop, because newbalance is always larger than 0.

How can I change this `while` loop so that it doesn't cause my code to run infinitely?

By the way:
With moderate numbers, the program runs for a long time and finally gives an answer. For the larger numbers, the program just keeps on going.

Comment: Why don't you add `print(newbalance)` inside your `while` loop instead of guessing what the value might be?

Comment: have you printed the values? it would help a lot!!

Comment: @MooingRawr: I think that's deliberate; the program seems to be calculating the minimum monthly payment to pay the full balance in 12 months, not increasing the monthly payment every year. (If it was increasing the monthly payment every year, you'd never pay it off this way.)

Comment: @MooingRawr we have to stop those private jokes... or not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bisection method will execute much quicker if you're allowed to use it in your assignment.  Will not help you though, if you're required to increment the monthly payment by .01.

```
static_balance = balance
interest = (annualInterestRate/12)
epsilon = 0.01
lo = balance/12
hi = balance

while abs(balance) > epsilon:
    balance = static_balance
    min_pmt = (hi+lo)/2
    for i in range(12):
        balance -= min_pmt
        balance *= 1+interest
    if balance > 0:
        lo = min_pmt
    else:
        hi = min_pmt
print("Lowest payment: ", round(min_pmt, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried this code and it fixed my problem with the code running too slow. However, it no longer produces the right answer.

Comment: Try this, if you're allowed to be within .01 of the payment.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I am allowed to be within .02 of the payment so it was perfect.

Answer (score 3):

This loop is not infinite, but will take a long time to resolve.  For very large values of `balance`, `monthlyPayment` will have to get very large in order to drop it past zero.